How to append object into a list of objects (not array) using bash
To a list of objects [{..},{..}], I want to add a new object using bash.
Example of my list:
[
      {
        "name" : "server",
        "image" : "server:latest",
        "essential" : true,
        "environment" : concat(
          [
            {
              "name" : "TZ",
              "value" : "${var.env_timezone}"
            }
          ],
          [
            for key, value in var.env_for_server:
            {
              "name" : key,
              "value" : value
            }
          ]
        ,
        "portMappings" : [
          {
            "hostPort" : 3000,
            "protocol" : "tcp",
            "containerPort" : 3000
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        "name" : "client",
        "image" : "client:latest"
      },
      {
        "name" : "nginx_gateway",
        "image" : "nginx_gateway:latest",
        "essential" : true,
        "portMappings" : [
          {
            "hostPort" : 80,
            "protocol" : "tcp",
            "containerPort" : 80
          }
        ]
      }
 ]

To this, adding:
{
  "name": "sidecar",
  "image": "sidecar:latest",
  "essential": true
 
}

So the result will be:
[
      {
        "name" : "server",
        "image" : "server:latest",
        "essential" : true,
        "environment" : concat(
          [
            {
              "name" : "TZ",
              "value" : "${var.env_timezone}"
            }
          ],
          [
            for key, value in var.env_for_server:
            {
              "name" : key,
              "value" : value
            }
          ]
        ,
        "portMappings" : [
          {
            "hostPort" : 3000,
            "protocol" : "tcp",
            "containerPort" : 3000
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        "name" : "client",
        "image" : "client:latest"
      },
      {
        "name" : "nginx_gateway",
        "image" : "nginx_gateway:latest",
        "essential" : true,
        "portMappings" : [
          {
            "hostPort" : 80,
            "protocol" : "tcp",
            "containerPort" : 80
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "sidecar",
        "image": "sidecar:latest",
        "essential": true
 
      }
 ]

I'm working on CI, so better to keep it one-two lines of code max.
Already tried some commands of jq, but nothing came out with merged, so trying my lucky in here.
Something like that when the files are respectively
jq '. += [input]' existing_containers.json new_container.json > updated_containers.json



What's up with concat and for key, value in var.env_for_server? That's not JSON. Assuming valid JSON inputs similar to your samples, . + [input] would be fine (in fact, there's even no need for += as it's by default the input being updated).

"CI" is a concept, not a specific product or format. If you are using a system that uses a JSON-like configuration language, identify it for the question.

@pmf , I know it's not a valid JSON, it was taken from terraform to describe container defention. I've hoped JQ can help me as is. and I know "CI" is a concept, I've just mention it to know the script should be short and without prompt anything

You don't need the =, it's just:
jq '. + [inputs]' existing new


I keep getting error jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 7, column 0. It's the same error with or without the =
